# delegation (while creating sideMenu, delegate? returns nil)

Tags: swift, null, delegates, delegation, side-menu

guys.
I'm asking for help. It seems a very easy task, but I can solve it for the whole day.
I'm trying to create a side menu using container view. When a user presses More button(barButtonItem), the whole view slide to the right and menu table appears. I know how to make it using Notifications. But I would like to solve it through delegation. Here is my storyboard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlikj.png)

and code:

```
import UIKit

class RootViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var leading: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var sideMenuIsOpen = false
    var sideMenu: MainViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sideMenu?.delegate = self
    }

    func openSideMenu() {
        toggleSideMenu()
    }

    func toggleSideMenu() {
        if sideMenuIsOpen {
            leading.constant = 0
        } else {
            leading.constant = 240
        }
    }
}
```

and:
        import UIKit

```
protocol SideMenuDelegate {
    func openSideMenu()
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SideMenuDelegate?

    @IBAction func toggleSideMenu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let delegateUnwrapped = delegate {
            delegateUnwrapped.openSideMenu()
        } else {
            print("nil")
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        BackgroundImageView.createBackground(insideView: self, image: .mainViewBackground)

    }
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: `sideMenu` seems to be `nil` the whole time – dod you forget to init the side-menu? probably, yes.

Comment: Yeah, I have already understood it. But I have no idea how to fix it. It doesn't work when I try "var sideMenu = MainViewController()".

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var sideMenu: MainViewController? // is nil 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sideMenu?.delegate = self
}
```

has no reference to the current displayed main , it's `nil` when you present the main from the Root give it the reference

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I'm new to programming. And make everything like Google said=) How can I give a reference?